# Running multiple python programs at the same time

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to run multiple, different python programs at the same time with only one interpreter installed?  I'm wanting to be able to run several different programs simultaneously, even ones I'm currently working on writing and wanting to be able to test then while I'm making changes to them.  Granted I haven't tried open multiple interpreter windows, just got the possible idea of that while looking up the idea here on the forum.  I would think if you did that, currently I have a program running so I don't want to interrupt it, any program would point to the original interpreter window wouldn't it?  Hence the question.

Comment: You can make use of [python threads](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html). Create a function you want each program to run on, and then start a thread from the main script.

Comment: You can open multiple program interpreters.  Give it a try.

Comment: Are you doing this with an IDE or just opening more command prompts? The second is fine.

Comment: Running a process has its own process ID which will not conflict with any other precess ID. The only restriction in running multiple process is the exclusive I/O on some resources. You can't listen on network port when another process is already listening on it, is just one example.